# How can I use name.com's and AWS's nameservers at the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, nameserver, amazon-route53

I want to use Titan Email extension but it requires changing my nameservers to Name.com's nameservers. The warning message is like that:

[image: Message 1]

[image: Message 2]

But I also need to use AWS's nameservers to use Route 53. I've tried to add 8 nameservers (4 of them were name.com's and the rest of it was AWS's) but when some time passes the webpage started giving NXDOMAIN error. What should I do?

**Edit**
Okay, I'm kinda inexperienced so didn't think I could actually add the Titan Email's DNS record from the Route 53 panel instead of Name.com's.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the messages. It would be highly unusual to require you to use specific name servers for your domain. What you need to do is add the appropriate records to Route 53 to support Titan’s email functionality. The first message wants you to verify the domain (usually through a provided TXT record). The second is probably because you’re asking Titan to make the DNS changes for you. You can do it yourself in Route 53. You’ll probably need to add specific MX, DKIM, DMARC and/or SPF records.

Comment: https://support.titan.email/hc/en-us/articles/360036853934-Setup-Titan-for-your-domain